# MS Access subform not allowing data entry after upgrading from 2003 to 2013

Tags: microsoft-access

I have "upgraded" an Access application by importing all the forms and code from an Access 2003 MDB file to a 2013 ACCB file. After relinking all of the tables most of the forms work properly but I have one subform that displays existing data properly but no longer allows me to enter new records.
The data entry consists of a combo box and a masked text box.

The combo box is populated from a SQL query. If there is a record the combo box works for the existing record but no longer appears for a new record (it used to in the old form).

I've compared all the properties between the old and new Access files and they appear to be the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that populates the subform did not include the ID field. I added the ID field and all seems to work now. I'm not sure why the query worked in the old version but not in the new without the ID.